# how do I get an onClick handler to move with the Image during an Animation?

Tags: java, android, animation, onclick, android-imageview

I have a simple animation of a circle going from about half way up the screen to near the bottom. It falls slowly and my intent is to make it clickable such that it will do something when it's clicked. I want it to be possible to click it anywhere from the start to the stop position.

The circle is implemented with an `ImageView` and I've added the `clickable` and `onClick` attributes. When I press where the circle *started* the `onClick` handler works as expected, however it does not seem to "track" the Image during animation.

I found the `AnimationListener` class and I was able to update my `ImageView`'s coordinates when the animation ended via the `onAnimationEnd()` handler, but there doesn't seem be a way to do this while the animation is running.

Is there a class/method I can use to update the `onClick` hander's location as my animation is moving? If not, is there a different type of animation that I should be using to accomplish my goals?

---

Relevant Code:

The xml layout for my ImageView:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/bubble"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:src="@drawable/bubble"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:onClick="popBubble"
   android:contentDescription="bubble"
   android:layout_below="@id/sun"
   />
```

The Java source code in the `onCreate` method to start the animation:

```
ImageView bubble = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubble);
Animation bubblefall = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bubble_fall);
bubblefall.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener());
bubble.startAnimation(bubblefall);
```

The Java source code that sets my AnimationListener:

```
private class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener{

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
  ImageView local = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubble);
  local.clearAnimation();
  local.offsetTopAndBottom(50);
```

The animation XML:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
   android:shareInterpolator="false"    
   android:duration="10000"    
   android:fillAfter="true"    
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
  <translate    
    android:fromYDelta="10%p"    
    android:toYDelta="60%p"    />
  <alpha    
    android:fromAlpha="0.7"    
    android:toAlpha="0.7"    />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AnimatorUpdateListener`:

```
bubblefall.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        //get animated value using
        animation.getAnimatedValue();

        //then handle the click listener
    }

});
```